# Scaleform Play a live video in texture?

Tags: video, textures, video-capture, scaleform

I would like to know if it's possible to play a live video, from a webcam for example, in a texture in Scaleform?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

To do this, you just need to replace the appropriate image inside the swf, with one that wraps the texture that contains your video.

You will need to have your video texture in a texture from the graphics API you are using (for example, in DirectX 11, you'd need an `ID3D11Texture2D`). You can create a Scaleform wrapper image around this, using the `TextureImage` class. You then need to find the resource within the SWF which you want to replace, and set the wrapper image as its image. Finally, you need to call `ForceImageUpdate` on the GFx::Movie, to propagate the texture change.

```
ID3D11Texture2D* videoTexture = ...;
Ptr<GFx::Movie> pMovie = ...;
Ptr<D3D1x::TextureManager> pmanager = ...;
Ptr<Render::Texture> scaleformTexture = *pmanager->CreateTexture( videoTexture, ImageSize(width, height));
Ptr<TextureImage> scaleformImage = * SF_NEW TextureImage(Image_R8G8B8, scaleformTexture->GetSize(), 0, scaleformTexture);
ImageResource* pimageRes = (ImageResource*)pMovie->GetMovieDef()->GetResource("name_of_resource");
pimageRes->SetImage(scaleformImage);
pMovie->ForceUpdateImages();
```

When you update the underlying `ID3D11Texture2D` (eg. with a new frame), the image in the Scaleform movie will also change. An example of how to do all this is shown within the TextureInSWF sample, which is a little more thorough than this code. If you have the XBoxOne SDK, there is also a KinectInSWF sample, which shows how to do this with the Kinect Camera (eg. a live video camera).

Comment: In fact, I have a problem with *pmanager->CreateTexture( videoTexture, ImageSize(width, height)); as there is no CreateTexture function with videoTexture's type as parameter.

Comment: sorry, should have been `ID3D11Texture2D`, not `ID3DTexture2D` (updated).